# filesystem path string method returning mixed \ and /

Tags: c++, std-filesystem

I have a C++ program where I use recursive iterator to go through folder that I provide as an argument to program.

Problem is that when I call .string on paths I get I get mixed \ and / in the path. 
Using .generic_string fixes this problem, but I wonder if this is a bug in VS2019 or allowed behavior.

To give some examples:
I give a/b as input to my program.

When I iterate over all the files and print them using .string
I get

> a/b\c\bla.txt
>
> a/b\d\lol.txt

and when I use .generic_string I get

> a/b/c/bla.txt
>
> a/b/d/lol.txt

Comment: Although windows supports either / or \ in most file operations I expect this is a bug in the implementation from microsoft.

Comment: Use Windows sensibilities and pass `a\b` to your program.  It otherwise doesn't matter at all, the OS handles either.

Comment: it's broken like this since MS-DOS, not using the normal slash... causing all this pain decades later...

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?  That would help provide context.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you convert the argument given by the user to an absolute path before using it with the directory iterator, otherwise, it'll display whatever the user supplied.

Example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int ftw(const fs::path& p) {
    // give an absolute path to the iterator
    for (const auto& f : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(fs::absolute(p))) {
        std::cout << f.path().string() << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

int cppmain(const std::string_view program, std::vector<std::string_view> args) {
    for (const auto& arg : args)
        ftw(arg);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return cppmain(argv[0], { argv + 1, argv + argc });
}
```